# Create/Edit posts and auto-redirect back to listing page

Tags: custom-post-types, redirect

Is there any way to possibly force a redirection to the post (type's) listing page (`edit.php?post_type=<post-type>`)?

<strike>**EDIT:** Since I got a LMGTFY link, let me clarify before I downvote it.</strike>

**Is there anyway to redirect the user forcibly to the post type's listing page AFTER they've already submitted the form to either edit the post or create a new post?**

Comment: My Original Comment: Yes, by adding a redirect. Either in your [server configuration](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/ApacheRedirect.html) or with a [Wordpress Redirect Plugin](http://tinyurl.com/4pfdzef).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- global `$post` or `$post_type` to check for your CPT;
- [Post Status Transitions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions) hooks to redirect on specific changes to the post;
- [`wp_redirect()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect).

Comment: Reading the Post Status Transitions article, I'm guessing I'd need to hook `publish_visitor` where `visitor` is my CPT? Thanks!

Comment: @Zack yep, that seems to be right.